# Inserting into two tables with the AccessDataSource

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, insert, null

I am attempting to insert into two tables at once, but it's inserting blank values into the first table, and then correctly inserting the values into the second table.  I can't figure out why the heck this is happening.  Here is my codebehind, I can post the rest of my code if needed.

```
Protected Sub btnSubmit_OnClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    AccessDataSource1.InsertCommand = "INSERT INTO [tableCourse] ([prefix], [course_number], [department], [name_first], [name_last], [credits], [title], [description]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);"
    AccessDataSource1.Insert()

    AccessDataSource1.InsertCommand = "INSERT INTO [tableFaculty] ([name_first], [name_last], [phone], [email]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"
    AccessDataSource1.Insert()

End Sub
```

EDIT:

Even when I comment out the second insert command, the first one still inserts null values.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try two different data sources. They're not meant to have the commands changed during a request.

Comment: I'm using a FormView, which seems to only allow one data source.

Answer (score 0):

I think the key here is that MS-Access is your data store and MS-Access only can cope with one command at a time. If this was MSSQL, you'd create one command, eg. "INSERT (...); INSERT (...)"  I think you will have to create two FormViews.

Comment: Alright... that will complicate things, but if there's no other option I guess that's what I'll have to do.